# ghostscript ignores part of pdfmarks

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have a problem with pdfmarks when "merging" PDF's with ghostscript 9.22. I have following situation:

## cover.pdf

In the properties of the document is mentioned

Title : cover.docx

Author: Edmond Egg

## input1.pdf

In the properties of the document is mentioned

Title : input1.docx

Author: Charly Cheese

## input2.pdf

In the properties of the document is mentioned

Title : input2.docx

Author: Susanna Sausage

## input3.pdf

In the properties of the document is mentioned

Title : input3.docx

Author: Martha Meet

## pdfmarks

```
[ /Title (Documents) 
[ /Author (Peters Workshop) 
[ /Subject (Repair Docs) 
[ /Creator (PPP PETERS PDF Producer) 
[ /DOCINFO pdfmark 
[ /FIT 
[ /CreationDate (D:20180927084000-01) 

[/Count 3 /Page 1  /Title (Repair Jobs ) /OUT pdfmark 
[/Page 1  /Title (cover page ) /OUT pdfmark 
[/Page 2  /Title (general overview ) /OUT pdfmark 
[/Page 69  /Title (cleaning and maintenance ) /OUT pdfmark 
[/Page 81  /Title ( visual inspection ) /OUT pdfmark
```

## My commandline:

```
gs -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNO_PDFMARK_OUTLINES -dPDFFitPage -o output.pdf cover.pdf input1.pdf input2.pdf input3.pdf pdfmarks
```

## My output.pdf file is as follows:

- The bookmarks are implemented correctly
- Title, Author are filled with the values of input3.pdf (always from the last PDF which I add to merge)
- other values are empty

Title: input3.docx

Author: Martha Meet

Subject: [empty]

Creator [empty]

CreationDate actual date/time

What do I make wrong that gs is ignoring part of my pdfmarks. As said before, bookmarks are set correctly.

Looking forward to your kind replies! Thanks to all in advance who try to help me. It is really appreciated!

Best regards

Michael

By the way: As I am new, I am not (yet) allowed to create TAGS. But I feel it could be helpful to add the tag "PDFMARKS". If somebody being allowed to create tags thinks the same, I would appreciate if you will do it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DocInfo pdfmarks are incorrect.

You've put :

```
[ /Title (Documents) 
[ /Author (Peters Workshop) 
[ /Subject (Repair Docs) 
[ /Creator (PPP PETERS PDF Producer) 
[ /DOCINFO pdfmark 
[ /FIT 
[ /CreationDate (D:20180927084000-01)
```

There is no pdfmark operator for any of those values. the one pdfmark in there has no values associated with it. I'm not at all sure what you think /FIT is going to do....

Something like this:

```
[ /Title (Documents) 
 /Author (Peters Workshop) 
 /Subject (Repair Docs) 
 /Creator (PPP PETERS PDF Producer) 
 /DOCINFO pdfmark
```

will probably work.

Comment: Thanks for you help KenS, it was so simple. I've changed it and now it is running well.